# Animation Not Working for UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiimageview

So I have this code here:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:1.0 options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{[obstacle setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 60, 60)];}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

This code doesn't do anything, and nor does it throw any errors. obstacle is an ImageView that is linked up to one of my images.

Also, UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut is giving me a yellow warning in XCode.

How can I fix my code to make this animation work correctly?

Comment: Did you check that `obstacle` isn't `nil` ?

Comment: It's not. Why would it be?

Comment: It could have, it's the main and most probable reason it could not work then.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut` and not `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut`. The first is an animation option, while what you are using, the second one, is an animation curve.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:1.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{

                     [obstacle setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 60, 60)];

                 }completion:nil];
```

Do not mix up `ENUM`s. At the core, they are all `NSInteger`s(one is signed other is unsigned), but both are acceptable, so the compiler will not give you a warning/error.

You can test this by passing `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` in the `options` block, and the compiler will still not give any error/warning, since this is also an `NSUInteger`.